# CloudFlare DNS / direct IP identifier

Tags: cloudflare

We started to use cloudflare at my work and I want to understand how the cloudflare knows that I put dns name at my browser and not direct IP.

I mean - how they knows if I put www.mysite.com and NOT 123.34.45.45 as URL on my browser.

Is there any flag at HTTP GET header or any other identifier ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's [how DNS works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

"The Domain Name System distributes the responsibility of assigning domain names and mapping those names to IP addresses by designating authoritative name servers for each domain"

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing that.

<strike>Inside apache instead of doing a public root directory, use VHosts instead they will only respond to a vhost requested. While its better than nothing it still can be displayed through an numerous amount of ways.</strike>
CloudFlare has released a module `mod_cloudflare` for apache, the module will log and display the actual visitor IP Addresses rather than those accessed by cloudflare! https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare (Answer by: [olimortimer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30078736/2801045))

I recommend you do it in PHP: Cloudflare's ips are stored in public so you can go view them [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) then check if the ip is from cloudflare (this will allow us to get the real ip from the http header `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP`).

If you are using this to disable all non cf connections or vice versa, i recommend you to have a single php script file that gets called before every other script such as a common.php or pagestart.php etc.

```
function ip_in_range($ip, $range) {
    if (strpos($range, '/') == false)
        $range .= '/32';

    // $range is in IP/CIDR format eg 127.0.0.1/24
    list($range, $netmask) = explode('/', $range, 2);
    $range_decimal = ip2long($range);
    $ip_decimal = ip2long($ip);
    $wildcard_decimal = pow(2, (32 - $netmask)) - 1;
    $netmask_decimal = ~ $wildcard_decimal;
    return (($ip_decimal & $netmask_decimal) == ($range_decimal & $netmask_decimal));
}

function _cloudflare_CheckIP($ip) {
    $cf_ips = array(
        '199.27.128.0/21',
        '173.245.48.0/20',
        '103.21.244.0/22',
        '103.22.200.0/22',
        '103.31.4.0/22',
        '141.101.64.0/18',
        '108.162.192.0/18',
        '190.93.240.0/20',
        '188.114.96.0/20',
        '197.234.240.0/22',
        '198.41.128.0/17',
        '162.158.0.0/15',
        '104.16.0.0/12',
    );
    $is_cf_ip = false;
    foreach ($cf_ips as $cf_ip) {
        if (ip_in_range($ip, $cf_ip)) {
            $is_cf_ip = true;
            break;
        }
    } return $is_cf_ip;
}

function _cloudflare_Requests_Check() {
    $flag = true;

    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']))   $flag = false;
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY']))       $flag = false;
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_RAY']))             $flag = false;
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_VISITOR']))         $flag = false;
    return $flag;
}

function isCloudflare() {
    $ipCheck        = _cloudflare_CheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $requestCheck   = _cloudflare_Requests_Check();
    return ($ipCheck && $requestCheck);
}

// Use when handling ip's
function getRequestIP() {
    $check = isCloudflare();

    if($check) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
    } else {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
```

To use the script it's quite simple:

```
$ip = getRequestIP();
$cf = isCloudflare();

if($cf) echo "Cloudflare :D<br>";
else    echo "Not cloudflare o_0";

echo "Your actual ip address is: ". $ip;
```

This script should help you out to check if the request is from CF and not directly though a ip address.