# issues with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Tags: php

currently I am trying to store my clients IP address on view, this proving to be more complicated then expected.

Here is the code I am currently using.

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
    $location = $details->country;
    print '<br>';
    print $details->country;
    print '<br>';
    print $details->city;
?>
```

which returns something that looks like this.

```
173.245.56.104
US
San Francisco
```

This IP and this location links back to a cloudflare server and not my actual IP address.

You can see that information here **cf-173-245-56-104.cloudflare.com**.

How ever when my buddies visit the same url which contains the document that is suppose to be giving the IP it gives them a different IP also connected to CloudFlare.

Example 1 being the following.

```
199.27.128.244
SG
Singapore
```

Which links to this cloudflare hostname **cf-199-27-128-244.cloudflare.com**.

And with a simple lookup you can see that it does not even provided the right GEO so for the reason I am looking to use this code, it would not even be viable if it's saying US based users are from Singapore or other countries.

[image]

So the question is, HOW can I get the **REAL** client IP address on visit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985518/cloudflare-and-logging-visitor-ip-addresses-via-in-php

Comment: @Matt Thank you SO much man!!