# Apache, whitelist real IP address when using Cloudflare

Tags: apache, cloudflare

I want to limit access to my website to certain IP addresses. I want to do this from Apache.

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{X-Forwarded-For}i !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule   "^"  "-"  [F]
```

replacing xxx with my own IP address. However, I'm still denied access.

The reason I thought this would work is because using %{X-Forwarded-For}i in the Apache log DOES show me my own IP address, and not Cloudflare's:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" real_ip
```

I have seen this question [CloudFlare and logging visitor IP addresses via in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985518/cloudflare-and-logging-visitor-ip-addresses-via-in-php), but it asks about PHP, not Apache. The Apache answer that was snuck in says to install Cloudflare's mod_cloudflare, but I'd hate to install something if it's not necessary.

I tried

```
%{HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP}i
```

based on the PHP answer, but it's nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this in your .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For 1.2.3.4$ coolpeople

<RequireAny>
    Require env coolpeople
</RequireAny>
```